# MS SQL, заполнение таблиц

Tags: sql

Есть база данных (MS SQL) Shop_BD, там 4 таблицы

```
CREATE TABLE type_book
(
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    type_book_fild NVARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE category_book
(
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    category_book NVARCHAR(45) NOT NULL 
);


CREATE TABLE name_book
(
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    name_book NVARCHAR(45) NOT NULL 
);


CREATE TABLE name_book
(
    id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    name_book_fild NVARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY(category_book_id, authot_id, type_book_id),
    category_book_id INT NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES category_book(id),
    authot_id INT NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES author(id),
    type_book_id INT NOT NULL
        FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES type_book(id)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Заполнил первые три таблицы, в одной типы книг, в другой категории, в третей авторы.
Все сработало а, вот с заполнением четвёртой что то не так

Заполнял так

```
INSERT INTO name_book (name_book_fild, category_book_id, authot_id , type_book_id) 
VALUES 
('Град обречённый', 
(select id from category_book where category_book = 'Фантастика' ),
(select id from author where name_author = 'Аркадий и Борис Стругацкие' ),
(select id from type_book where type_book_fild = 'Преключение' )
);
```

При первом разе всё работает как надо ,а вот при втором
не работает и выдаёт

`Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'category_book_id', table 'Shop_BD.dbo.name_book'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.`
Второй раз заполнял так же только данные другие.

```
INSERT INTO name_book (name_book_fild, category_book_id, authot_id , type_book_id) 
VALUES 
('Ореховый будда', 
(select id from category_book where category_book = 'Роман' ),
(select id from author where name_author = 'Борис Акунин' ),
(select id from type_book where type_book_fild = 'Детектив' )
);
```

Как сделать что бы поля заполнялись как в первый раз?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка говорит о том, что вы пытаетесь вставить значение `NULL` в столбец, который не допускает пустые значения. В вашем примере - это колонка `category_book_id` и значение для неё вы берёте подзапросом

```
select id from category_book where category_book = 'Роман'
```

Это значит, что подзапрос не нашёл в таблице `category_book` значение `'Роман'` и вернул `NULL`. Убедитесь, что такое значение там есть и повторите попытку.

---

*Так же обратите внимание на то, что колонки в таблицах лучше не называть аналогично имени таблицы.*

Comment: Спасибо! Буду внимательней!